# STM32L496 ADC with HAL and DMA: only one byte updated in results buffer

Tags: stm32

In the context of an STM32L496 project, I've setup the ADC with two input channels as follows

[image]

And the DMA like this:

[image]

I'm using the following code to start the conversion and display the results:

```
adc_done = 0;
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*) adc_results, 2);

while (!adc_done) {
  HAL_Delay(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  printf("ADC%d: %.4X", i + 1, adc_results[i]);
}

HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc1);
```

For some reason, it seems that only the very first byte of my `adc_results` buffer gets updated. All the other bytes remain at their default values, which I've set to `0xAA`.

What could be the reason for this? I'm suspecting that this is more of a DMA than an ADC issue.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? Unfortunately I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, I was able to fix it by setting `DMA Continuous Requests` to `Enabled`.